# Losing click information after page refresh

Tags: jquery

I came up with the following for my NavBar. Well, after refreshing the current page using F5 I am losing my click information, everything according to my NavBar falls back to default, like u've never clicked on a link :/

```
    <script>
    "use-strict";   
     $(document).ready(function()
    {
    /*
    $(".default").show();
    */

    $("#navSalon>ul>li a").click(function()
    {
        $("#navSalon>ul>li a").next().hide();
        $(this).next().show();
    });

    $("#navSalon>ul>li a").click(function()
    {
        $("#navSalon>ul>li a").children().attr("src", "dot1.png");
        $(this).children().attr("src", "dot0.png");
    });
});   
</script>
```

Comment: Of course it falls back to default - you are reloading the page. If you want changes to persist, act server side.

Comment: can't I just local-store additional information according to what the user has actually clicked before refreshing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Because HTTP is stateless**. When you refresh the page, It is a new HTTP Get request going to the server and getting the results.

If you want to keep the changes you made, you need to keep that in a persistent medium. You may consider the following

**1) Database**: Store your changes in database and load it again on further requests

**2) Session** : Store your changes in Session variable , If you work with a server side language. The life time of this is till the user session ends.

**3) Cookies** : Store these in browser cookies